# Youtube theater mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have side bar that i would like to slide down the page on a button click. div A needs to then slide over to fill the space, exactly like the youtube player does in theater mode:

Layout 1

```
----------------------------
|                     |    |
|       A             | S  |
----------------------|    |
|                     |    |
|       B             |    |
----------------------------
```

Layout 2

```
----------------------------
|                          |
|       A                  |
---------------------------|
|                     | S  |
|       B             |    |
----------------------------
```

I am not asking how to do the animation, but rather the simplest way to accomplish the basic functionality. I need to toggle freely between these two states. One caveat is I have a swf embedded in div A, and I cannot disturb it (element.detach() is out for div A).

I am not limited to only css or only js, and I only need to support back to IE10 so what are some good modern solutions?

Comment: Modern would probably be `flexbox`. Why don't you inspect YT's implementation, and see what's going on under the hood?